# Putting two Integers into a list from a single list comprehension

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I need to find all primes ± 2 in list comprehension however after looking i cant find out how to do it, so far i have:

```
primeTwins :: Integer -> [Integer]
primeTwins x = [x+2 | x <- [2..x], prime x]
```

However this obviously only produces primes+2 when i need primes-2. (prime x finds if the number is a prime). If it isnt possible, i need 2 compregensions but i also dont know how to go about that either. From my research i havent found anything relavant so any help would be helpful.
Thats for any help given

Answer (score 3):

You can use another generator that takes `x-2` and `x+2`, and then yields both:

```
primeTwins :: Integer -> [Integer]
primeTwins x = [ y | x <- [2..x], prime x, y <- [x-2, x+2] ]
```

It is however possible that the same element occurs twice in the list. For example, 3 and 7 are both prime, so that means that 1 and 5 are generated because 3 is prime; and 5 and 9 are generated because 7 is prime, so then 5 is generated twice.

Comment: Thank you so much! I plan on ordering the list then removing duplicates, unless there is a better alternative

Comment: @Owen: the list is already more or less ordered in the sense that the next element only is at most 3 smaller than the next element. You thus can remove duplicates with a dedicated function that should only look back a few places.

Comment: In all honesty i wouldnt know how to do that either, im very new to/useless at haskell. Thanks for your help though